# Getting Index already exists on table error entity framework code first migrations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am getting the error - The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_address_unique' already exists on table 'dbo.Addresses'.  The index in question is a composite index that I created with code first EF version 6.  Here is the code in the DbContext class -

`// create unique address composite index based on properties
            // address1 property
            modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().Property(t => t.address1)
                .HasMaxLength(250)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasUniqueIndexAnnotation("IX_address_unique", 0);
            // city property
            modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().Property(t => t.city)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasUniqueIndexAnnotation("IX_address_unique", 1);
            // state property
            modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().Property(t => t.state)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasUniqueIndexAnnotation("IX_address_unique", 2);
            // postal code property
            modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().Property(t => t.postal_code)
                .HasMaxLength(20)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasUniqueIndexAnnotation("IX_address_unique", 3);`

This creates the following DbMigration when you run the command Add-Migration CreateUniqueIndexAddressesTable.

```
public partial class CreateUniqueIndexAddressesTable : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Addresses", "address1", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 250));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Addresses", "address2", c => c.String(maxLength: 250));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Addresses", "city", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Addresses", "state", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Addresses", "postal_code", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 20));
        CreateIndex("dbo.Addresses", new[] { "address1", "city", "state", "postal_code" }, unique: true, name: "IX_address_unique");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.Addresses", "IX_address_unique");
        AlterColumn("dbo.Addresses", "postal_code", c => c.String());
        AlterColumn("dbo.Addresses", "state", c => c.String());
        AlterColumn("dbo.Addresses", "city", c => c.String());
        AlterColumn("dbo.Addresses", "address2", c => c.String());
        AlterColumn("dbo.Addresses", "address1", c => c.String());
    }
}
```

If you delete the index and then excersize the code which is setup to run if there are any database migrations then all works well (no errors) as expected but if you delete the entire database (in a dev environment of course) and re-create the empty database then you will again see this error.  Why is this error even happening in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I had face same issue working with code first approach with **mysql** database. If you are using mysql database try to remove `dbo` prefix from your code. So for Up write  `CreateIndex("Addresses", new[] { "address1", "city", "state", "postal_code" }, unique: true, name: "IX_address_unique");`. For down write `DropIndex("Addresses", "IX_address_unique");`.
Hope it should work for u.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me.  I may try using data annotations instead.